# How to calculate nanoseconds from 1800

Tags: java, datetime, long-integer, nanotime, system-clock

I'm trying to calculate the number of nano seconds that passed from:
11-Nov-1831 00:00:00.00

to a given date.

I tried to use alot of packages but none of them succed in the mission
(the closest was Instant)

What's the best way to achive this mission?

Comment: Can you compute the fixed number of nanoseconds from 11-Nov-1831 to 01-Jan-1970 and just add that offset to your normal timestamps?

Comment: That's a good solution but if the start date will change, we will need to calcuate it again.

Comment: Why that particular start date, out of curiosity?

Comment: No one knows, but I'll try to find out :D

Comment: 11-Nov-1831 00:00:00.00 in which time zone? Do you have trustworthy time zone data for that time zone this far back? I believe that it’s from before GMT came into use (outside UK at least).

Comment: Nanoseconds since the date you mention can be held in a `long` until year 2124, so 100 years from now. A potential new “year 2000 problem” might worry me just a bit.

Comment: i used System default timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Instant` is still the best option, but you may need some helper objects.

For instance, to create the start date (replace the `Z` with a different time zone or offset as needed):

```
Instant start = Instant.parse("1831-11-11T00:00:00Z");
```

Then take the given date. You can parse it, or use conversion methods. For instance, if you have a `LocalDateTime` (use a different `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset` as needed):

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-06-09T20:56");
Instant instant = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

Now get a duration:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(start, instant);
long nanos = duration.toNanos();
```

Comment: I think that the number we calculate is to big,
the result of :
<code>
Instant start = Instant.parse("1831-11-11T00:00:00.00Z");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2007-12-03T10:15:30.00");
</code>
is 5555981730000000000 which not make sense.
There is a way to solve it with this tools?

Comment: @emal The number is not too big. `Duration#toNanos` is documented as throwing an exception if the result would be too long. The maximum of a `long` is enough for about 292 years worth of nanoseconds. And there are indeed 5,555,988,930,000,000,000 nanoseconds between  1831-11-11T00:00:00Z and 2007-12-03T10:15:30Z. See all this math [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/6PaZL4). Note also that `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type to use here.

Comment: @BasilBourque you're right about `LocalDateTime`, I used it as an example. The instant comes from the `ZonedDateTime` that was created by applying the `ZoneId` to the `LocalDateTime`.